# PowerShell Compress and Read-Only using Send-To

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new in PowerShell scripting so if what I am asking is not possible by all means tell me that.

I would like to create a PowerShell script that would accept the send-to command.

The purpose of the script is to change the files to read-only and then compress those files. I’d like to be able to select multiple files in file explorer then right-click, send to (Script)

Is this something that is possible? Thanks!

**Update 1**

Alright, I have it were it will select files using file explorer then pass them into the script. The read-only is functioning correctly. Just need to sort out the compression.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    Multiselect = $true # Multiple files can be chosen
    Filter = 'Images (*.jpg, *.png)|*.jpg;*.png' # Specified file types
}

[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

$path = $FileBrowser.FileNames;

If($FileBrowser.FileNames -like "*\*") {

    # Do something before work on individual files commences
    $FileBrowser.FileNames #Lists selected files (optional)

    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $path){
    Get-ChildItem ($file) |
        ForEach-Object {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
        }
    }
    # Do something when work on individual files is complete
}

else {
    Write-Host "Cancelled by user"
}
```

Comment: For the Email in Powershell v1.0 bit, you could read this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4d64f04d-abdc-48a8-8076-114eddb4864b/powershell-v1-send-email-with-attachment

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions on a powershell script, or how to integrate a script into the windows shell menu?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2** Alrighty I got it all working, does what I need it too. Here it is if anyone has any interest in it.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    Multiselect = $true # Multiple files can be chosen

}

[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

$path = $FileBrowser.FileNames;

If($FileBrowser.FileNames -like "*\*") {

    # Do something before work on individual files commences
    $FileBrowser.FileNames #Lists selected files (optional)

    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $path){
    Get-ChildItem ($file) |
        ForEach-Object {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
            compact /C $_.FullName
        }
    }
    # Do something when work on individual files is complete
}

else {
    Write-Host "Cancelled by user"
}
```